# LDAP Authentication Error Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am following the guide ( https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ ) and have the following classes:

Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
        
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().formLogin();
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getAll()
    {
        return "Welcome All";
    }
}
```

LDAP config file (in classpath)

```
dn: dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: springframework

dn: ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: subgroups

dn: ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: space cadets

dn: ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: "quoted people"

dn: ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: otherpeople

dn: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Ben Alex
sn: Alex
uid: ben
userPassword: $2a$10$c6bSeWPhg06xB1lvmaWNNe4NROmZiSpYhlocU/98HNr2MhIOiSt36

dn: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Bob Hamilton
sn: Hamilton
uid: bob
userPassword: bobspassword

dn: uid=joe,ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Joe Smeth
sn: Smeth
uid: joe
userPassword: joespassword

dn: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Mouse, Jerry
sn: Mouse
uid: jerry
userPassword: jerryspassword

dn: cn=slash/guy,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: slash/guy
sn: Slash
uid: slashguy
userPassword: slashguyspassword
```

I have tried to log in several times by using given uid and password through form login and each and every time below error occur in the browser

[image]

```
 Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:8389
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Do I have to explicitly start the LDAP server somewhere else or is there something I miss out?

edited -
application.yml

```
spring:
  ldap:
    embedded:
      port: 8389
      ldif: "classpath:ldap-data.ldif"
      base-dn: "dc=springframework,dc=org"
      url: "ldap://localhost:8389/"
```

Comment: No. It is embedded ldap.  Do you have 3 dependencies `spring-ldap-core`, `spring-security-ldap` and `unboundid-ldapsdk`?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai yes, i have